# Using Instagram API to automatically show recent user images by username?

Tags: wordpress, instagram, instagram-api

I have a feature on a WordPress website that I'm working on where an Instagram feed is displayed on a user's page. They are able to enter their IG username. I want to be able to simply display the last 10 images from their feed. I would do this manually but there will be many, many users on this website.

I'm not clear from their documentation how to do this in an automatic way. I can show a feed for an individual account if I register via that account on the Instagram Developers page, create an access token, and figure out my client ID. This is a manual (and tedious) process as far as I can see.

I tried even looking if I can scrape the Instagram page as the format is just `https://www.instagram.com/username` but they almost appear to obfuscate the class names to prevent this.

Is there no way to simply (via a plugin or otherwise) just poll Instagram for a certain public user's images and return them?

Comment: I suspect you're going to need to get that client ID & access token the hard way!

Comment: Does this help: https://www.instagram.com/developer/embedding/ ?